# Проблемы текста привилегии "Инструменты Модератора"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

#### Что такое модерация?

Если вы являетесь одним из самых опытных пользователей, мы рассчитываем, что вы будете помогать в управлении сообществом и служить пример**ом**.

*(несогласованное окончание)*

---

Также есть проблема в ссылках.

#### Доступ к инструментам модерации

последний пункт:

- Полная история **просмотров** каждого из разделов **обзор** всеми пользователями.
  Чтобы получить доступ к этим инструментам, нажмите на ссылку **обзор** в верхнем меню, а затем на ссылку инструменты в заголовке.

Стоит поправить следующим образом:

- Полная история действий *всех* пользователей в каждом разделе из [очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).

Чтобы получить доступ к этим инструментам, нажмите на ссылку [очередь проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) в верхнем меню, а затем на ссылку [инструменты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools) в заголовке.

**Изменения:**

- *добавлен абзац после описания возможности, так как перечисление возможностей должно было закончиться*
- *переформулирован текст для большей понятности*
- *изменённое название раздела: обзор → очередь проверок*
- *изменённая ссылка с первого подсвеченного слова обзор на:

  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues; был лишний символ кавычки*
- *изменённая ссылка со второго подсвеченного слова обзор на:
  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review; была ссылка на

  https://meta.stackexchange.com/review*
- *добавлена ссылка на инструменты

  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools*

Comment: Тимофей, вы тут пишете, как будто изменения уже произведены. Но в данный момент ничего из этого не исправлено. Где вы исправляли? Может, слетела правка?

Comment: Так как я не знаю, где это править более-менее напрямую, я опубликовал изменения здесь, поставив метку дефект и понадеялся, что это привлечёт внимание модераторов =) Видимо, в какой-то момент я подзабыл про этот вопрос и забыл напомнить модераторам о том, что стоит внести эти изменения. Добавил метку предложение, теперь должно быть лучше заметно.

Comment: Я уже Николасу напомнил в чате.

Comment: [Опубликовал улучшенную версию раздела в ответе на похожий вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1617/6).